# ShapeDrawables not Showing up in Android

Tags: android

I've been trying to show 4 rectangles in a layout by drawing with shape drawables. For some reason my 3rd and 4th ones won't draw. Any idea what's wrong?

```
public class CropDraw extends View {
private ArrayList<ShapeDrawable> pieces = new ArrayList<ShapeDrawable>();

public CropDraw(Context context, int color, int... coords) {
    super(context);
    int x = coords[0];
    int y = coords[1];
    int len = coords[2];
    int wid = coords[3];
    int thickness = 5;

    // Create and set colors for the 4 sides
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        pieces.add(new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape()));
        pieces.get(i).getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    pieces.get(0).setBounds(x, y, wid, thickness);
    pieces.get(1).setBounds(x, y, thickness, len);
    pieces.get(2).setBounds(x, y + len - thickness, wid, thickness);
    pieces.get(3).setBounds(x + wid - thickness, y, thickness, len);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    pieces.get(0).draw(canvas);
    pieces.get(1).draw(canvas);
    pieces.get(2).draw(canvas);
    pieces.get(3).draw(canvas);

  }

}
```

Comment: Are you certain they're not drawing outside the bounds of the screen?

Comment: Pretty certain, it seems like whenever I choose starting coordinates other than x and y (both 0) it won't draw them